# openstreetmap with less details

Tags: google-maps, svg, openstreetmap

Is it possible to speed up mapping with OSM by removing features and details (minor roads, bus stops, etc) -- or is that somewhat irrelevant to the tile download and rendering process.

aka, Are the SVG details added/removed on client or server side.

Further how are those 'church: invisible' type of instructions set

TIA

Perhaps that is a general mapping question; given that an engine (possibly) operates in much the same way at least when it comes to tiles and SVG details. And I simply don't know that process.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear about which specific process your are talking.

The tiles you see on http://openstreetmap.org are `PNG`, not `SVG`. The [share menu](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Browsing) allows to export the current view to SVG and some other formats. This resulting SVG is created server-side. Of course using less detail would speed up the SVG creation process But this process involves several other operations like querying the data base which won't benefit much from reduced details (ignoring the time to transfer the data between the database and the SVG creation process).

The PNG rendering will also depend somehow on the amount of detail but likewise there are a lot more operations necessary for rendering a single tile. I don't expect a large speedup by removing a few features.

Also note that there are several different [renderers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering) available and each will behave differently. And there is also the possibility of creating [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) which move some of the tile creation load from the server-side to the client-side. Here the amount of detail will slightly influence the server-side and significantly more the client-side, especially low-end systems.

Still I have no idea what these things have to do with mapping - the process of editing maps and adding/updating information.